# cast in oracle 9i while migrating from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

Now i am migrating my system from SQL to ORACLE 9i.

Here USERID is of NUMBER(38) type
  and DATA is of LONG type in SQL.

I  have table named :

PEOPLE  and DBATABLE and i run the following code in oracle but found the following error...
**ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes:**

```
SELECT P.USERID
FROM PEOPLE P
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT data
    FROM DBATABLE
    WHERE Name = 'USER'
) R ON CAST(data AS VARCHAR(50)) = CAST(P.USERID AS VARCHAR(50))
WHERE P.USERLOGID = 1000
    AND R.data IS NULL;
```

So help me for finding my error.
I have missed somewhere but could not find what i missed.

Comment: Why do you migrate to an ancient version of Oracle instead of a more recent version?

Comment: When you say *"migrating from SQL"* do you mean *"migrating from SQL-Server"*? And if yes, what is the "mysql" tag for?

Comment: It's totally useless to migrate to a version that has been de-supported for over 5 years now. And the `LONG` datatype has been deprecated for over 10 years now. Nobody should use that any more.

Answer (score 0):

Cast P.USERLOGID to the correct datatype - I'm almost positive it wasn't migrated to the intended type. Let me know if this helps.. thanks, Brian

Comment: I must cast P.USERID or P.USERLOGINID...I am confused at answer.

Comment: WHERE P.USERLOGID = 1000 ...should be... WHERE CAST(P.USERLOGID AS NUMERIC(8, 0)) = 1000

or whatever type it needs to be. (integer?)